# RHEL 7: mount windows cifs share failed

Tags: rhel, mount, file-sharing, cifs

It may look like it is duplicate question but in context of RHEL 7, it is not.

As RHEL 7 does not have **mount.cifs** binary present in /sbin, I want to know what else can be done to mount windows cifs share on Linux machine.

**cifs** mounts the windows share for sometime and as required I can unmount it.
I do not want cifs share to be mounted at boot time. My script shouls do mount and unmounts operations for me.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your company policy allows you to use `CIFS` then please make sure cifs utility is installed.

```
# lsmod |grep cifs
cifs                  293313  3
```

if not then install it

```
# yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils
```

or

```
# yum install cifs-utils
```

After installing CIFS utility you should be able to find `mount.cifs` command.

To mount while booting you will required to add its entry under `fstab` file

`example:`

```
`//10.10.*.*/folder/to-share /mountpoint cifs username=harry,password=XXXXXX,rw,user 0 0`
```

or

```
`//10.10.*.*/folder/to-share /mountpoint cifs credentials=/root/.smbfile,rw,user 0 0`
```

`.smbfile` > add Windows machine credentials

```
username=harry
password=XXXXXX
```

with the help of above entries you can change your scripts accordingly.

You may also use `autofs`

## Find the 'CIFS' alternatives links:

Mount Linux NFS Share on Windows 7​
`http://www.hackourlife.com/mount-linux-nfs-share-on-windows-7/`

How to install Client for NFS on Windows for a UNIX-to-Windows migration
`http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324055`

NFS client for Windows 7 (Microsoft Community)
`http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/...indows-7/42aae25d-d077-4ff9-abdf-7314a589c46d`

Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2
`http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391`

Comment: About company policy: I downloaded iso from Red hat network. I have installed it on my virtual machine.